# How to put app widgets on lockscreen in android?

Tags: android

I read on 'developer.android.com' that from Android 5.0 and higher, **lock-screen widgets** are not valid. If this is the case, then how is it possible for an app called **'Slidejoy'** to show widgets on lockscreen, when the *enable lockscreen* feature is activated in the app?
I tried searching for the same but the only things I found were that I need to install apps like *Notifidgets*, *NotifWidgets* to achieve that functionality.
If it's possible in those apps, then there must be some way.

**Kindly help.**
Thanks.

Comment: Most likely, it is not showing anything on the system lockscreen, but rather has implemented its own insecure lockscreen replacement.

Comment: u tried with slidejoy?

Comment: With slidejoy, it is showing advertisements on the system lock screen

Comment: If it is, that's a security flaw that needs to be addressed.

Comment: So are you telling that there is no way out to put widgets on lockscreen in Android 5.0 and above?

Comment: Correct. Certain notification types (e.g., `MediaStyle`) allow for light interactivity on the lockscreen.

Comment: But **Slidejoy** is working absolutely fine...there does not seem to be any security flaw in that...

Comment: Have you tried Slidejoy?

Comment: "there does not seem to be any security flaw in that" -- any app that can superimpose windows over the lockscreen and react to touch events on those windows can prevent the user from unlocking their device. This is a security flaw.